# Better way to find sub strings in Datastore?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an aplication where an user inputs a name and the aplication gives back the adress and city for that name

The names are in datastore

```
class Person(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True) 
    address = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    city = ndb.StringProperty()
```

There are more than 5 million of Person entities. Names can be formed from 2 to 8 words (yes, there are people with 8 words in his names)

Users can enter any words for the name (in any order) and the aplication will return the first match.("John Doe Smith" is equivalent to " Smith Doe John")

This is a sample of my entities(the way how was put(ndb.put_multi)

```
id="L12802795",nombre=["Smith","Loyola","Peter","","","","",""], city="Cali",address="Conchuela 471"
id="M19181478",nombre=["Hoffa","Manzano","Linda","Rosse","Claudia","Cindy","Patricia",""], comuna="Lima",address=""
id="L18793849",nombre=["Parker","Martinez","Claudio","George","Paul","","",""], comuna="Santiago",address="Calamar 323 Villa Los Pescadores"
```

This is the way I get the name from the user:

```
name = self.request.get('content').strip()  #The input is the name (an string with several words)
name=" ".join(name.split()).split() #now the name is a list of single words
```

In my design, in order to find a way to find and search words in the name for each entity, I did this.

```
      q = Person.query()

      if len(name)==1:
                names_query =q.filter(Person.name==name[0])
      elif len(name)==2:
                names_query =q.filter(Person.name==name[0]).filter(Person.name==name[1])
      elif len(name)==3:
                    names_query =q.filter(Person.name==name[0]).filter(Person.name==name[1]).filter(Person.name==name[2])
      elif len(name)==4:
                names_query =q.filter(Person.name==name[0]).filter(Person.name==name[1]).filter(Person.name==name[2]).filter(Person.name==name[3])
      elif len(name)==5:
                names_query =q.filter(Person.name==name[0]).filter(Person.name==name[1]).filter(Person.name==name[2]).filter(Person.name==name[3]).filter(Person.name==name[4])
      elif len(name)==6:
                names_query =q.filter(Person.name==name[0]).filter(Person.name==name[1]).filter(Person.name==name[2]).filter(Person.name==name[3]).filter(Person.name==name[4]).filter(Person.name==name[5])
      elif len(name)==7:
                names_query =q.filter(Person.name==name[0]).filter(Person.name==name[1]).filter(Person.name==name[2]).filter(Person.name==name[3]).filter(Person.name==name[4]).filter(Person.name==name[5]).filter(Person.name==name[6])
      else :
                names_query =q.filter(Person.name==name[0]).filter(Person.name==name[1]).filter(Person.name==name[2]).filter(Person.name==name[3]).filter(Person.name==name[4]).filter(Person.name==name[5]).filter(Person.name==name[6]).filter(Person.name==name[7])

       Person = names_query.fetch(1)
       person_id=Person.key.id()
```

**Question 1**
Do you think, there is a better way for searching sub strings in strings (ndb.StringProperty), in my design. (I know it works, but I feel it can be improved)

**Question 2**
My solution  has a problem for entities with repeted words in the name.

If I want to find an entity with words "Smith Smith" it brings me "Paul Smith Wshite" instead of "Paul Smith Smith", I do not know how to modify my query in order to find 2(or more) repeated words in  Person.name

Comment: In my sample code ( `This is a sample of my entities(the way how was put(ndb.put_multi)`) 
**Replace** _"nombre"_ for _"name"_ and _"comuna"_ for _"city"_  in order to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate a list of all possible tokens for each name and use prefix filters to query them:

```
class Person(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
  address = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
  city = ndb.StringProperty()

  def _tokens(self):
    """Returns all possible combinations of name tokens combined.

    For example, for input 'john doe smith' we will get:
    ['john doe smith', 'john smith doe', 'doe john smith', 'doe smith john',
     'smith john doe', 'smith doe john']
    """
    tokens = [t.lower() for t in self.name.split(' ') if t]
    return [' '.join(t) for t in itertools.permutations(tokens)] or None

  tokens = ndb.ComputedProperty(_tokens, repeated=True)

  @classmethod
  def suggest(cls, s):
    s = s.lower()
    return cls.query(ndb.AND(cls.tokens >= s, cls.tokens <= s + u'\ufffd'))


ndb.put_multi([Person(name='John Doe Smith'), Person(name='Jane Doe Smith'),
               Person(name='Paul Smith Wshite'), Person(name='Paul Smith'),
               Person(name='Test'), Person(name='Paul Smith Smith')])
assert Person.suggest('j').count() == 2
assert Person.suggest('ja').count() == 1
assert Person.suggest('jo').count() == 1
assert Person.suggest('doe').count() == 2
assert Person.suggest('t').count() == 1
assert Person.suggest('Smith Smith').get().name == 'Paul Smith Smith'
assert Person.suggest('Paul Smith').count() == 3
```

And make sure to use `keys_only` queries if you only want keys/ids. This will make things significantly faster and almost free in terms of datastore OPs.

Comment: Thank @Dmytro Sadovnychyi , it is an smart solution. (I took me a while undestand it, Im newbie). But it does not work for names larger than 8 words (there are more 40320 permutations wich is bigger than 1MB, so I cannot put it in datastore). 
For names with less than 7 words works fine. I improved replacing:
        return [' '.join(t) for t in itertools.permutations(tokens)] or None  
for:
        m=[' '.join(t) for t in itertools.permutations(tokens)]
        return list(set(l)) or None

Comment: Thanks @DmytroSadovnychyi

Comment: You are welcome! Please make sure to accept the answer if it's solved the problem for you.